# how to get rid of if else block using optional methods

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a flow based on options returned by methods.

My question is: Is there a way to build a flow that splits in case of getting for example `Optional<int> (some)` and executing another flow in the other case in a nice way? (not of using if else switch ternary statements)

**The question really is how to  get rid of this if else block:**

can you please provide an example???

```java
...
.filter( f -> getFolderLastIdx( f ).isPresent() )
.flatMap( newLoadFile ->  executeCommand( Id ) )
.ifPresent( newLoadFile -> {
    if ( executeCommand( Id ) ) {
        moveFileStatusFlow.accept( newLoadFile, transactionId, "success" );
        executePostScriptCommand( transactionId, batchId );
    } else {
        moveFileStatusFlow.accept( newLoadFile, transactionId, "fail" );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Optional`, as well as its primitive counterparts, inherently can't handle this kind of task. It's not designed to completely replace control flow constructs. Instead, it focuses on getting rid of those endless null checks.